# Validate URL parameter in Blazor and respond with 404

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to validate the URL in a Blazor server-side page. The parameter value needs to be a value in an enum. If the URL value isn't one of the enum values, I'd like to return an HTTP response 404.

I realise that Blazor's way of handling stuff is a bit different from vanilla ASP.NET, so I'm not even sure this is possible. The examples I've managed to find all navigate to a 'not found' page. That might work, but I'd prefer a 404 error.

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
page "/{Value?}"

<h1>@ParsedValue.ToString()</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public MyEnum ParsedValue { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
        {
            MyEnum parsedValue;
            if (!Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(Value, out parsedValue))
            {
                // return 404 not found
            }
            ParsedValue = parsedValue;
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Apples,
        Oranges,
        Bananas
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* navigate to a 404 page.

In your component, you can use NavigateTo with the forceLoad option - this avoids the Blazor router.

```
@inject NavigationManager navman
@page "/{Value?}"

<h1>@ParsedValue.ToString()</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public MyEnum ParsedValue { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
        {
            MyEnum parsedValue;
            if (!Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(Value, out parsedValue))
            {
                navman.NavigateTo($"404?{navman.Uri}",true);
            }
            ParsedValue = parsedValue;
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Apples,
        Oranges,
        Bananas
    }
}
```

Then map an endpoint to handle the 404 route in startup.cs

```c#
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.Map("404", rq =>
    {                    
        rq.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        rq.Response.WriteAsync(Get404(rq.Request.QueryString.ToString().Substring(5)));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
string Get404(string url)
{
    return $@"
        <h1>404 - Page not found</h1>
        <p>{url}</p>
        <a href=""/"">Home</a>
        ";
}
```

If you wanted a Razor page to handle the display of the 404 message instead of an actual 404 status response, you could also use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` to redirect that 404 to an actual Razor page/View to make things pretty - but then you could have had that within the Blazor SPA, so I doubt you want that - you did ask for a true 404.